# After a failed kali linux install, my non-related ubuntu removed the sidebar, all snap apps, login screen, and auto screen lock

Tags: login, 22.04, lock-screen, boot-repair

I am very new to Linux and have used it as my main OS for less than 2 weeks.
I have tried to install Kali Linux on my computer on a different SSD from my main Ubuntu SSD. I failed to install Kali and decided to stop mid-install. After that, I plugged in my main SSD and booted up my machine and saw an unusual login screen that looked like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhTF6.jpg) , and all apps installed with Snap were not accessible on the show application menu but could still be used when typing their name in the terminal. My screen never locks. It just dims like it's about to lock but stays that way forever. If I press the lock option, the screen goes black and after the first login or when I use sudo, it never asks for a password and lets everyone in.
My sidebar is also gone.

All my settings say that auto screen lock is enabled and that I have a sidebar.
How can i bring everything back to default?

Comment: Enter your grub (check this forum on how to) and select the ubuntu partion.

Comment: i single-boot Ubuntu, my grub is 2.06-2ubuntu7

Comment: I see what I believe is a `xdm` greeter on a likely windows host running a VM?  There is no mention of a VM, and `xdm` isn't installed by default so your system has been altered but your picture has me confused given it looks like a VM (`xdm` *or a greeter should operate full screen without border your picture clearly shows*)

Comment: Try running either `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` or `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` and choose any but `xdm`.

Comment: thank you Terrance but for future people you will receive an error, restart and everything will come back to normal

Comment: Also see https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5361/55205